# How to detect invalid command in speech recognition c#?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I have a problem. I'm creating a speech recogntion program in c#. I want my program to be able to detect an incorrect command.

I tried using the try and catch but i think i got it wrong.

```
void Default_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        string speech = e.Result.Text;

        switch (case)...     
        {
              //Commands
        }  

    }
try
{
    if (speech != e.result.Text)
    Bill.Speak("You have given an invalid command. Please try again.");
}
catch{}
```

How can I do this properly?

Comment: Since you haven't said how to detect an "invalid command", it's hard for anyone to help here. Does "invalid" mean not one of the ones in the `switch` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an default to your switch case

```
  switch (speech)
  {
    case "1":
      Bill.Speak("Command 1");
      break;
    case "2":
      Bill.Speak("Command 2");
      break;
    default:
      Bill.Speak("You have given an invalid command. Please try again.");
      break;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a default for your switch.  so

```
    switch (case)...     
    {
          //Commands
          default: // not recognized
            Bill.Speak("You have given an invalid command. Please try again.");
    }
```

Comment: Do still have to use the try and catch block?

Comment: no, try/catch is not relevant to what you're wanting to do. @JohnMarcusOlegario

Answer (score 0):

add 
     Default:
      Bill.Speak("I donot understand command");

to your case statement